# Using System.Text.Json DeserializeAsyncEnumerable to deserialize non-root items

Tags: c#, .net-core, streaming, system.text.json

I'd like to process a large JSON response (a large list of measurements) from a webserver in a streaming fashion using `JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable()`. Problem is that the array of measurements is wrapped in a header JSON document. For example:

```
public record Header(string Id, Measurement [] Measurements);
public record Measurement(string Timestamp, decimal Value);
```

The `DeserializeAsyncEnumerable()` specifies that it only works for root level items. Is it possible to still use this method and somehow skip the wrapping class?

I've looked into writing a custom `JsonConverter`, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

I've also tried to create a property of type `IAsyncEnumerable<Measurement>` on the Header but even if I don't iterate the collection it has already created all the measurement objects.

As for my scenario: I want to go through the file without actually loading the entire file into memory. Simple example: calculate an average over the measurement values. I don't need the header but since it's produced by an external service I cannot change the contract. In the past, with an XML reader I could relatively easily do this but it appears it's not as easy with system.text.json.

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you're actually trying to achieve. What JSON are you trying to deserialize, and what is causing a problem? (It sounds like you've *got* the header document, so you should be able to deserialize the whole thing... why are you trying to "skip" the wrapping class?)

Comment: If you are looking to do **streaming deserialization** of huge JSON files, then this is only implemented when the root JSON container is an array.  See [Announcing .NET 6 Preview 4: Streaming deserialization](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-6-preview-4/#streaming-deserialization): *It only supports reading from root-level JSON arrays, although that could be relaxed in the future based on feedback.* ...

Comment: .. and also [`[API Proposal]`: Support streaming deserialization of JSON objects #64182](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/64182) which was closed as a dup of [Developers should be able to pass state to custom converters. #63795](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/63795) -- which is still open.

Comment: You could do everything manually as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55429664/3744182) to [Parsing a JSON file with .NET core 3.0/System.text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54983533/3744182) -- which is very difficult with System.Text.Json for some reason.  Alternatively, you could use Json.NET where it is easy, see [Parse large JSON file with the bulk of the data inside a property of the root object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34959969).

Comment: Or if you are not trying to implement streaming deserialization of huge JSON files, then please [edit] your question to clarify your requirement as suggested in [ask].  Thanks!

Comment: What are you going to do with the `Measurements` values as you stream them in?  Since you can't fit them all in memory you must be doing something for each one individually, such as collecting statistics or streaming to disk.  Can you share what that is?

Comment: Thanks john and dbc for your replies.

As for my scenario: I want to go through the file without actually loading the entire file into memory. Simple example: calculate an average over the measurement values. I don't need the header but since it's produced by an external service I cannot change the contract. 

In the past, with an XML reader I could relatively easily do this but it appears it's not as easy with system.text.json. 

@dbc, indeed the answer you've described at least makes it possible to do it manually, but I was hoping to rely on something built into the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of .NET 8, System.Text.Json only implements streaming [SAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML)-like parsing for root level JSON arrays.  As stated in [Announcing .NET 6 Preview 4: Streaming deserialization](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-6-preview-4/#streaming-deserialization):

> `JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable`... only supports reading from root-level JSON arrays, although that could be relaxed in the future based on feedback.

Unfortunately the restriction has not been relaxed as of .NET 8.  For confirmation, see [[API Proposal]: Support streaming deserialization of JSON objects #64182](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/64182) which was closed as a duplicate of [Developers should be able to pass state to custom converters. #63795](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34959969) -- which is still open.

So what are some possible workarounds?

**Firstly**, you could use `Utf8JsonStreamReader` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55429664/3744182) by [mtosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7217527/mtosh) to *[Parsing a JSON file with .NET core 3.0/System.text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54983533/3744182)* to stream through the measurements, deserialize each one, and process it as required:

```
using var jsonStreamReader = new Utf8JsonStreamReader(stream, 32 * 1024);

int totalCount = 0;
decimal totalValue = 0;

while (jsonStreamReader.Read())
{
    if (jsonStreamReader.CurrentDepth == 1 && jsonStreamReader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
    {
        var propertyName = jsonStreamReader.GetString();             
        if (string.Equals(propertyName, "Measurements", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (!jsonStreamReader.Read())
                throw new JsonException();
            if (jsonStreamReader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartArray)
            {
                while (jsonStreamReader.Read() && jsonStreamReader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray)
                {
                    var measurement = jsonStreamReader.Deserialize<Measurement>();
                    // Do something with Measurement, such as compute the total measurement value and count.
                    totalCount++;
                    totalValue += measurement.Value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var average = totalValue / totalCount;
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7iyQ9Q).

**Secondly**, you could use a psuedo-collection that implements `ICollection<Measurement>` but only processes the added measurements without actually accumulating them.

E.g., define the following classes:

```
public record Measurement(string Timestamp, decimal Value);
public record Header<TCollection> (string Id, TCollection Measurements) where TCollection : IEnumerable<Measurement>;

public class TotalMeasurementCollection : AgggratingCollectionBase<Measurement>
{
    public int TotalAdded { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalValue { set; get; }

    // Do something with Measurement, such as compute the total measurement value and count.
    public override void Add(Measurement item) => (this.TotalAdded, this.TotalValue) = (this.TotalAdded + 1, this.TotalValue + item.Value);
};

public class AgggratingCollectionBase<TItem> : ICollection<TItem>
{
    public virtual void Add(TItem item) {}
    public bool Contains(TItem item) => false;
    public void CopyTo(TItem[] array, int arrayIndex) => ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(array);
    public int Count => 0;
    public bool IsReadOnly => false;
    public bool Remove(TItem item) => false;
    public void Clear() {}
    public IEnumerator<TItem> GetEnumerator() => Enumerable.Empty<TItem>().GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
}
```

And now you will be able to do:

```
var result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Header<TotalMeasurementCollection>>(stream);
var average = result!.Measurements!.TotalValue / result!.Measurements!.TotalAdded;
```

This trick is non-obvious but has the advantage of working with any serializer.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vLV717).

**Thirdly**, you could switch to Json.NET which supports streaming deserialization of individual objects inside a huge JSON file natively by using [`JsonTextReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm) to read through the file.  See e.g.:

- *[How to parse huge JSON file as stream in Json.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43747477/3744182)*.
- *[Parse large JSON file with the bulk of the data inside a property of the root object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34959423/3744182)*.

Comment: Thanks for the very complete answer. I i hadn't thought of using this collection trick. It's a nice one!